# pandas cx_Oracle query results

Tags: python, sql, database, oracle, cx-oracle

The below code runs fine. However, if I run it once, and then delete the table in the Oracle Database manually, the below code keeps returning the same result , as if it has been cached somewhere and keeps returning the same result over and over again.

```
import cx_Oracle 
import pandas as pd


conn = cx_Oracle.connect("foo/foo@localhost/foo")
query='SELECT * FROM FOO_TABLE'
df = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn)
cursor.close()

print(df)
```

Comment: The code you've pasted isn't an isolated example. What is `query`? What is `query_orcl()`?

Comment: Sorry AKX, have cleaned it up a bit and added some imports. Thank you for the heads up

Comment: `x` is still not defined...

Comment: So if you run this code (as a standalone script), then `DROP TABLE FOO_TABLE` or similar, then re-run the code, it still print out the contents?

Comment: That is correct. Same table content still prints out, although I have deleted the content.

Comment: *delete the table in the Oracle Database manually* - do not forget to `COMMIT` the delete. Until the `delete` is not *commit*ed all other session see the data.